# SceneKit: Using Blender mesh for volume generation of particle system

Tags: scenekit, particle-system

I am trying to create a particle system in SceneKit.  I use the

`particleSystem.birthLocation = .volume`

option on a SceneKit node.  This is working fine for built-in SceneKit shapes like SCNBox or SCNCylinder but now I need to make more complex meshes in Blender for use as the emitter.  As  simple test I tried exporting the default Box you get in Blender.  However, when I try the exported .dae file I get the following error in the console.

`[SceneKit] Error: Cannot use volume generation on a generic mesh. fallbacking on surface`

Even the surface emitter it creates is not correct and consists of 3 triangles.

I've tried various options in the Blender export but I can't get this to work.  Anyone have any ideas?